# Link to a slide on a slide show on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my gallery of images, I want to be able to click on one of them and be directed to a slide of the slider (on another page).

My code pretty much looks like the code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow).

The other page is a gallery of images with empty `<a>` tags.

Got any Ideas?

Comment: Can you share with us the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a good answer but.. add ID to your images(slides or whatever) and use link to your id ?

```
<div id="photo1">Photo 1</div>

<div href="#photo1">Jump to photo 1</div >
```